# ant war - putting file parallel to web.xml

Tags: ant, spring-ws

I am trying to use spring webservice with ant. spring webservice requires spring-ws-servlet.xml and sample.xsd file to be put in war file parallel to web.xml.

I am trying this war command and it is putting parallele to web-inf folder instead inside of it. Please let me know what should i modify to put it inside web-inf folder.

```
<copy file="config/ws/spring-ws-servlet.xml" tofile="lps/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml" />

<war warfile="dist/ODG.war" webxml="config/web.xml">
            <lib dir="lps/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <classes dir="lps/WEB-INF/classes" />
            <fileset dir="lps/ws"/>
</war>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [ant manual states](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), add a `webinf` element to the war task to add files into the `WEB-INF` directory.

```
<war warfile="dist/ODG.war" webxml="config/web.xml">
    ...
    <webinf>
        <fileset dir="config/ws" includes="spring-ws-servlet.xml"/>
    </webinf>
</war>
```